Ancient Egyptian ph2 and th2 clusters esp as reflected in Greek transcriptions
on the off chance that someone might find this interesting, there is an issue that seems not to have been addressed in the literature (which is itself interesting because, given the limited data and the vast numbers of PhDs in these fields, one would have expected dozens of learned articles on the subject plus a dissertation or two), namely, the reflexes of such clusters (by h2 I mean the sound usually taken to be have been [x], officially transcribed as ḫ (h with breve below in case that is not displaying correctly), which clusters in papyruses sometimes give πχ or φχ resp. τχ θχ but in literary sources seem (so I believe anyway but am open to correction if I am mistaken) φ and θ.  If I happened to be right, that would allow several etymologies hitherto missed, e.g., of Pharos, the island across from where Alexandria was built.  If anyone knows of any literature that addresses this issue (I have been looking and can't find any) or has any ideas or even just an interest in this--and maybe would like to help--I would be grateful and will acknowledge any help in print of course.
